# Jquery mobile pageshow, pagehide countdown to redirect or exit on will

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

So I'm trying to set up a page in Jquery Mobile that will countdown for 30 seconds.
It has to have the following capabilities:

(1) begin countdown on pageshow
(2) when countdown expires, redirect to new page
(3) if user clicks away (pagehide) before countdown expires, exit the timer function and reset count.

So here is my attempt. I have placed the code under the `<div data-role="page" id="pay">`.

```
<script>
            $("#pay").live("pageshow",function(){
            alert("show!");
            var sec = 10;
            var timer = setInterval(function() { 
               $('#seconds').text(sec--);
               if (sec == 5) { alert("5 seconds mark")};
               if (sec == -1) {
                  document.location = "cuentas";
                  clearInterval(timer);
               } 
            }, 1000);
            });

            $("#pay").live("pagehide",function(){
                alert("hide!");
                clearInterval(timer);
                var sec = 10;

            });

</script>
```

I get the "show!" alert. I get the "5 second mark" alert. And I get the "hide!" alert when I switch pages before countdown expires.
But if I leave the page, say at 8 seconds, my menu bar freezes up - I can no longer navigate to other pages -- and I see the 5 second alert! The interval function never ended... I'm not sure what is wrong.

Another note ---

```
$("#pay").live("pagehide",function(){
               clearInterval(timer);
                var sec = 10;
                alert("hide!");

            });
```

When I do this, I never see the alert.....

I've tried `return false;`, `return;`, `break;`. Any ideas how to kill that interval countdown  function on page hide?

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Besides that, it looks like your timer variable is local to the function called on pageshow

```
$("#pay").live("pageshow",function(){
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
```

I think you would have to pull it out in order to pass it to clearInterval from the function to be called on pagehide

Also, perhaps unrelated, but you have a semicolon that is off:

```
if (sec == 5) { alert("5 seconds mark")};
```

should be

```
if (sec == 5) { alert("5 seconds mark");}
```

Comment: Ah good point. Thanks for the help. This helped get me closer.... So I have it now set outside the function. The _first_ time I go to the page, I can navigate away with the correct behavior. However if I return to the page, without refreshing the jqm app, I get the odd behavior where the pagehide function again doesnt clear the interval....

Comment: Make sure you unbind the events on cleanup. I would suggest using on instead of live, and make sure you call off for both of the events. If you don't unbind the events you will probably get weird behavior. Vote up if the answer helped you?